# SignalR on Azure: Failed Connection Handshake

Tags: azure, signalr

I am getting an error in my application whereby the connection over wss:// is failing.

The browser gets a 200 status code, and I see the log line in ASP.NET Core app that looks like:

> {"@t":"2019-09-06T16:46:58.0850696Z","@m":"Failed connection handshake.","@i":"ebdbcf97","@l":"Error","EventId":{"Id":5,"Name":"HandshakeFailed"},"SourceContext":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext","TransportConnectionId":"qLt39WTMAY4t-Q4vyRTGrg","RequestId":"0HLPISG9A2QAE:00000006","RequestPath":"/hubs/results","CorrelationId":null,"ConnectionId":"0HLPISG9A2QAE"}

Browser error:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://frontend.env.company.com/hubs/results?id=qLt39WTMAY4t-Q4vyRTGrg' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

The application is running behind an nginx in a kubernetes cluster hosted on Azure. It's fronted by Azure CDN which routes certain /paths to this origin/endpoint.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is that Azure CDN with Premium Verizon does not support WebSockets. Have moved away from that as a solution and used nginx instead, which works beautifully.